# Managing users with Pirhana CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

What is the best way to manage users with PirhanaCMS?
I would like to prevent some users from adding content (posts etc...) in some categories and prevent that some sites be listed for some users. (For people who don't know it, PirhanaCMS is a micro CMS programmer oriented).

I would like to use the sites features because I'm working on a project in which I'll have  a "network" of several sites managed by different entities of an organization. I would like that each entity be only able to see its own site but that the big organization at the top be able to manage every sites. Moreover, within a site I would like that some users be only able to edit some part of the site.

Are these features built-in ? Otherwise what is the best way to implement them myself around the CMS ?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and EF5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at System > Permissions in the manager area you can see that there are permissions you can give to groups for different parts of the manager interface.

There's however currently no built in support for restricting access to different site trees, but you are free to add a feature request for this at [GitHub](http://github.com/tidyui/piranha) or maybe participate by implementing it and sending a pull request!

Comment: Just one more question ! Do you have any advice about the best place to put it to keep the code clean ?

Comment: I've added a feature request for this at GitHub. Let's have the implementation discussion there! https://github.com/tidyui/Piranha/issues/247